# Changing from a tekmar 518 to vivint smart thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I want to change my tekmar 518 thermostat to a Vivint smart thermostat. The issue I'm having is that the tekmar has an R and an RH wire and the Vivint thermostat only has slots for an RC and an RH wire. They both have C & W wires/slots. Wondering how I wire the new Vivint thermostat? I have radiant/hydronic floor heating.

[image: Circuit Board]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image: Control Board]

[image: Control Board]

[image: Tekmar Setup]

Comment: Please upload pictures of all the wires and how they are connected at both ends .. at the old thermostat and at the boiler.  Unusual to have R, Rh, and W all with wires connected on a heat-only system.  Some pair of those should turn on heating but not all three.  You can add pictures by clicking "Edit" above and uploading or pasting in jpgs into your question.

Comment: If you have the "switching relay" such as on page 6 of the Tekmar manual, that supplies separate R and Rh wires to the thermostat, we'll need to see the documentation for that "switching relay" to understand that.   It's possible you cannot use the Vivint thermostat.  Also, if your system uses the S1 terminal on the thermostat to monitor slab temperature, you cannot use the Vivint thermostat.  The Tekmar one is designed specifically for radiant heating.

Comment: Thank you Jay613, I have posted the photos. The control board is a bit of a jumble, hopefully you can make it out. The system does not use the s-1 terminal on the thermostat to monitor slab temperature.

Comment: What is the model of the controller box?   There are two black and two white wires in the thermostat.  What terminals, exactly, are they connected to?  It looks like you have hot water and 4 heating zones controlled by this controller.  Are you replacing only one thermostat?   The Rh and W wires probably go to the R and W terminals of one of the zones.  The R and C wires probably go to R and C terminals on the left side.  Can you confirm that?  We really need to know the controller model # to understand why it sends two R signals to the thermostat.

Comment: Label those wires at the thermostat.  Don't wait, do it now.  If you forget to label them and disconnect the old thermostat base you'll be sorry.

Comment: Yes, already labelled :)

Comment: Will post a photo of the controller box diagram with model #.  Yes, I have hot water (DHW) and four heating zones. Replacing only one thermostat. Can't confirm until tomorrow exactly where wires are connected, but I think you are correct that Rh and W wires go to the R and W terminals of one of the zones and R and C wires go to R and C terminals on the left side.

Comment: Too bad so many people ask for help but never confirm if the help they've received took care of the problem or not...

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a guess, and hoping to confirm or correct this once more information is available.

##### What to do

The "R" connection from the Tekmar thermostat should go to "Rc" in the Vivint one.

The other three (Rh, C, W) should all go to the same corresponding terminals.

##### Why (guessing)

The "R" wire, along with C, is meant to provide power to the Tekmar thermostat.   The Vivint one as with most smart thermostats can take power from Rc for systems where the heating doesn't provide power and there is no A/C.

What is puzzling is why the Rh wire would not serve that purpose.   My guess is the controller's "priority" function (if you use it) that gives boiler priority to hot water over home heating, functions by disconnecting Rh.   That's a pure guess, but I can't think of an other reason there would be two R wires.  There are also some other clever tricks played by the controller, that I haven't fully researched, but the significant result of all of them is that Rh may not be a reliable source of power for the thermostat.

Fortunately the old thermostat already had a separate R/C pair of wires and the new one can use those, via it's Rc/C terminals.

##### What's frustrating

1. That your system is constructed with two or three two-wire cables to each device instead of a single multicolor one.  That SUCKS!
2. The thermostat manual shows mostly configurations where R and Rh are jumpered.  It shows ONE configuration where they are not.  But the manuals *that I have seen* for the controllers only show configurations where the thermostat is jumpered, and there is no discussion of separate R and Rh signals from the controller (in the several Tekmar manuals I've seen.)

Comment: Yes, the controller does have a priority function that gives boiler priority to hot water over home heating. I have hooked the wires up exactly as you suggested with "R" connection from the Tekmar thermostat going to "Rc" in the Vivint one and the other three (Rh, C, W) going to the same corresponding terminals. Seems to be working. Only issue is that the zone is continually calling for heat, even though the thermostat has reached the desired temperature. The only time the zone doesn't call for heat is when the priority zone (DHW) is on.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?  At the thermostat, R/Rh should be 0V always.  R/C and Rh/C should be 24V, perhaps always, or perhaps when priority isn't active.  W/C should be 24V when there is call for heat, or 0V otherwise.

Comment: I do have a voltmeter and I will check.